# Return Even numbers from numeric array using ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have a numeric array I want to return even no. from this array. I know this is very easy in python or any other language, but I am not able to do same in ReactJs.
here is my code

```
import "./styles.css";
const numbers = [2,5,3,7,8,6]
const evenNum = []
export default function App() {
  for(let i=0; i<=5; i++){
    if(numbers[i]%2 == 0){
        evenNum.push(<span key={i}> evenNum[i]</span>)
    }
  }
  return (
    {evenNum}

  );
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {evenNum}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: try with return `<div>{evenNum.forEach(e=>e)}</div>` or `<div>{evenNum.map(e=>e)}</div>`

Comment: Also check what you are exactly to push in `evenNum`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your intent is for rendering the numbers without any markup try with Fragment:

```
import { Fragment } from 'react';
```

```
return evenNum.map((n) => <Fragment key={n}>{n}</Fragment>)
```